ASP.NET MVC area issue on IIS 10
I have an existing ASP.NET MVC application (on .NET 4.8), and I have recently added an area to the application (area is registered and the route is mapped).
When I deployed the app to IIS, it works as expected on the local server (server-localhost:port), but when I try to access the area via the domain name, I get redirected to the default app page and there seems no way to access the newly added area.
During my research, I came across URL Rewriting rules; I tried everything I found but no use.
Website uses HTTP, not HTTPS
Server: Windows Server 2022
IIS version: 10

I found the reason behind it as I was using Cookies (without user consent) to store data which caused the issue, as a solution, I moved the data to Session variables and now all is good.
